# Reinstall 14.04 fails to recognise separate /home. Can I recover old home?

Tags: 14.04, home-directory

**Previous Working System :** Upgrade of 13.10 to 14.04 with /home on separate partition. 
This worked fine after I removed my second graphic board.

**Reinstall** After some weeks I decided to do a fresh install but chickened out when I saw the option to reinstall keeping documents, music etc. So I chose reinstall. This worked but left me with a new /home directory.

The old /home directory is present on another partition.  How can I set up so this is recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want to keep the separate partition for /home or you are fine with having everything on one partition (assuming your "new /home directory" is not on a separate partition).

If one big partition is okay or your new /home is on an additional new partition, then do this:
Copy the files from the old home to the new one, log out and back in (so settings you made in files you copied back get applied) and delete the old home afterwards.
There are lots and lots of ways to copy those files, probably just using the file manager would work if you set it to display hidden files and copy those too. Other ways include "cp" and "rsync" (see their manpages).
Deleting the old /home partition could be done using "gparted" (easiest) or various other tools.

If you want to keep the separate old partition, then you need to edit your /etc/fstab file so the partition is automatically mounted to /home at boot. Afterwards the unwanted new /home directory is hidden behind the other one, or you can delete it.
For information on how to edit that file, look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: That's great thanks. I'll do this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: old /home directory now mounts after modifying the /etc/fstab. Firefox and Thunderbird work as before using the old data. Many thanks for this rapid help.